mongod command instantly shutdowns
When i hit the command mongod these logs are coming:
{"t":{"$date":"2024-06-17T10:58:33.254+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-06-17T10:58:33.254+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Initialized wire specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":21},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":21},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":6,"maxWireVersion":21},"isInternalClient":true}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-06-17T10:58:33.267+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648602, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen in use."}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-06-17T10:58:33.270+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationDonorService","namespace":"config.tenantMigrationDonors"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-06-17T10:58:33.270+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationRecipientService","namespace":"config.tenantMigrationRecipients"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-06-17T10:58:33.270+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":5945603, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Multi threading initialized"}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-06-17T10:58:33.270+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"TENANT_M", "id":7091600, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Starting TenantMigrationAccessBlockerRegistry"}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-06-17T10:58:33.270+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":96287,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/data/db","architecture":"64-bit","host":"Efe-MacBook-Pro.local"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-06-17T10:58:33.270+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"7.0.11","gitVersion":"f451220f0df2b9dfe073f1521837f8ec5c208a8c","modules":[],"allocator":"system","environment":{"distarch":"aarch64","target_arch":"aarch64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-06-17T10:58:33.270+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Mac OS X","version":"23.2.0"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-06-17T10:58:33.270+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-06-17T10:58:33.271+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":5693100, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Asio socket.set_option failed with std::system_error","attr":{"note":"acceptor TCP fast open","option":{"level":6,"name":261,"data":"00 04 00 00"},"error":{"what":"set_option: Invalid argument","message":"Invalid argument","category":"asio.system","value":22}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-06-17T10:58:33.273+03:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20557,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"DBException in initAndListen, terminating","attr":{"error":"NonExistentPath: Data directory /data/db not found. Create the missing directory or specify another path using (1) the --dbpath command line option, or (2) by adding the 'storage.dbPath' option in the configuration file."}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-06-17T10:58:33.273+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784900, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Stepping down the ReplicationCoordinator for shutdown","attr":{"waitTimeMillis":15000}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-06-17T10:58:33.274+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4794602, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Attempting to enter quiesce mode"}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-06-17T10:58:33.274+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":6371601, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the FLE Crud thread pool"}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-06-17T10:58:33.274+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784901, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the MirrorMaestro"}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-06-17T10:58:33.274+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784902, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the WaitForMajorityService"}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-06-17T10:58:33.274+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":20562,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutdown: going to close listening sockets"}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-06-17T10:58:33.274+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784905, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the global connection pool"}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-06-17T10:58:33.274+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784906, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the FlowControlTicketholder"}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-06-17T10:58:33.274+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":20520,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Stopping further Flow Control ticket acquisitions."}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-06-17T10:58:33.274+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784918, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the ReplicaSetMonitor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-06-17T10:58:33.274+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784921, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the MigrationUtilExecutor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-06-17T10:58:33.274+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22582,   "ctx":"MigrationUtil-TaskExecutor","msg":"Killing all outstanding egress activity."}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-06-17T10:58:33.274+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784923, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the ServiceEntryPoint"}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-06-17T10:58:33.274+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784928, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the TTL monitor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-06-17T10:58:33.274+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":6278511, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the Change Stream Expired Pre-images Remover"}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-06-17T10:58:33.274+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784929, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Acquiring the global lock for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-06-17T10:58:33.274+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4784931, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Dropping the scope cache for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-06-17T10:58:33.274+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20565,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Now exiting"}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-06-17T10:58:33.274+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":8423404, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"mongod shutdown complete","attr":{"Summary of time elapsed":{"Statistics":{"Enter terminal shutdown":"0 ms","Step down the replication coordinator for shutdown":"0 ms","Time spent in quiesce mode":"1 ms","Shut down FLE Crud subsystem":"0 ms","Shut down MirrorMaestro":"0 ms","Shut down WaitForMajorityService":"0 ms","Shut down the transport layer":"0 ms","Shut down the global connection pool":"0 ms","Shut down the flow control ticket holder":"0 ms","Shut down the replica set monitor":"0 ms","Shut down the migration util executor":"0 ms","Shut down the TTL monitor":"0 ms","Shut down expired pre-images and documents removers":"0 ms","Wait for the oplog cap maintainer thread to stop":"0 ms","Shut down full-time data capture":"0 ms","shutdownTask total elapsed time":"1 ms"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-06-17T10:58:33.274+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23138,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down","attr":{"exitCode":100}}

I also tried:
mongod --port 27018 (which is different from default)  to check if i had running proccesses.
But did not work. Still same.

The important line is

NonExistentPath: Data directory /data/db not found. Create the missing directory or specify another path using (1) the --dbpath command line option, or (2) by adding the 'storage.dbPath' option in the configuration file.

I'd guess this means that at least the /data path part does not exist.
It spells out your options: make a folder for it to use and specify that on the command line with --dbpath, or set the path in the configuration file.

Thanks! On macos we are not able to write files to root directory. So i did
mkdir -p ~/data/db and
mongod --dbpath ~/data/db  saved my day.
